# Installed python 2.6.6 by accident and now files for Python 3.4.1 ruined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.6

I run a Windows 8 computer and was initially coding in Python 3.4.1. But for a school assignment, I needed to code in Python 2.6.6. After installing 2.6.6 I realized that it completely removes Python 3.4.1 from my system. I still need Python 3.4.1 so there a way to recover it. I already tried re-installing Python 3.4.1 but it didn't work.

Comment: The usual Python installer is perfectly happy installing multiple versions of Python. They each get installed into their own directory. Chances are that your `PATH` environment variable is now set up to find Python 2.6 first.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it using PATH but I was able to find a way to get Python 3.4 back. Your tip on how they all have their own directory helped. Thanks